# What type of differential equation is the hydrostatic equilibrium?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What type of differential equation is the hydrostatic equilibrium?
\begin{align}
\frac{dP}{dr}&=\frac{-G·M(r)·\rho(r)}{r^2}\\
\end{align}

Comment: 1st order, separable.

Comment: just looked a little more at it, isn't it a first order linear ordinary differential equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First order seperable linear non-homogeneous ordinary differential equation with constant coefficients.